# Find if string is in variable

Tags: python

I have this script to get the variable with the highest value + it's name. If there are more variables with the same highest variable then it will return all of them. If you don't understand what I am saying, this is what I mean: [Check if something in a dictionary is the same as the max value in that dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439954/check-if-something-in-a-dictionary-is-the-same-as-the-max-value-in-that-dictiona)

**Script**

```
if request.method == "POST":
        d = {'g_dirt4': g_dirt4, 'g_destiny2': g_destiny2, 'g_southpark': g_southpark, 'g_codww2': g_codww2, 'g_bfront2': g_bfront2, 'g_reddead2': g_reddead2, 'g_fifa18': g_fifa18, 'g_motogp17': g_motogp17, 'g_elderscrolls': g_elderscrolls, 'g_crashbandicoot': g_crashbandicoot}
        print("g_dirt4", g_dirt4, "g_destiny2", g_destiny2, "g_southpark", g_southpark, "g_codww2", g_codww2, "g_bfront2", g_bfront2, "g_reddead2", g_reddead2, "g_fifa18", g_fifa18, "g_motogp17", g_motogp17, "g_elderscrolls", g_elderscrolls, "g_crashbandicoot", g_crashbandicoot)
        #print (max(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
        result = [(n,v) for n,v in d.items() if v == max(d.values())]
        print ("Resultaat", result)
        if 'g_dirt4' in result:
            print ('Dirt 4')
        if 'g_destiny2' in result:
            print ('Destiny 2')
        if 'g_southpark' in result:
            print ('South Park: The Fractured but Whole')
        if 'g_codww2' in result:
            print ('Call of Duty: WWII')
        if 'g_bfront2' in result:
            print ('Star Wars Battlefront II')
        if 'g_reddead2' in result:
            print ('Red Dead Redemption 2')
        if 'g_fifa18' in result:
            print ('FIFA 18')
        if 'g_motogp17' in result:
            print ('MotoGP™17')
        if 'g_elderscrolls' in result:
            print ('The Elder Scrolls Online: Morrowind')
        if 'g_crashbandicoot' in result:
            print ('Crash Bandicoot N. Sane Trilogy')
        return redirect("https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/8487168_300x300")
```

The problem is that it only returns ("Resultaat", result) and ("g_dirt4", g_dirt4, "g_destiny2"..........) which look like this for example:

```
2017-06-12 11:29:10 g_dirt4 8 g_destiny2 5 g_southpark 4 g_codww2 5 g_bfront2 6 g_reddead2 5 g_fifa18 6 g_motogp17 8 g_elderscrolls 7 g_crashbandicoot 5
2017-06-12 11:29:10 Resultaat [('g_dirt4', 8), ('g_motogp17', 8)]
```

but it doesn't return these:

```
if 'g_dirt4' in result:
        print ('Dirt 4')
......
```

I want to check which game is in the result. How do I do this?

EDIT:

Full script https://pastebin.com/eKVnjJka

Comment: You're building `result` as a list of pairs. Then you're checking if various strings are elements of the list (i.e. equal to any of those pairs). Strings are not equal to pairs, so your `if`s will not match. Perhaps you want to build a list of keys instead of a list of pairs.

Comment: This comes out like I said: Resultaat [('g_dirt4', 8), ('g_motogp17', 8)]

Comment: where are these variables declared? `g_dirt4, ...`

Comment: Changed thread with a pastebin of the full code. Thought it wasn't really necessary.

Comment: How do I do that? @khelwood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you might find the set of keys that map to the maximum value in your dictionary.

```
d = {'g_dirt4': g_dirt4, 'g_destiny2': g_destiny2, ... }

max_value = max(d.values())
maximal_keys = { k for k,v in d.items() if v==max_value }

if 'g_dirt4' in maximal_keys:
   etc.
```

I used a set for the `maximal_keys` because it is more efficient for lookups, but a list would also work.
If you're using Python 2, you might prefer to use [`d.itervalues()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) and [`d.iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) instead of [`d.values()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) and [`d.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) respectively.

*Edit*

The `if` statements would be unnecessary if the keys in your dictionaries were the actual titles, instead of these `g_...` strings.

```
d = {'Dirt 4': g_dirt4, 'Destiny 2': g_destiny2, 'South Park: The Fractured but Whole': g_southpark, ... }

max_value = max(d.values())
maximal_keys = [ k for k,v in d.items() if v==max_value ]
for title in maximal_keys:
    print (title)
```

In fact that way, you could skip the `maximal_key` generation and go straight to printing.

```
max_value = max(d.values())
for title, value in d.items():
    if value==max_value:
        print (title)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works :) But how do I print them in one line actually? Making all the possible if statements would take too long. So that it checks what games are in the maximal_keys, without saying .... in maximal_keys. Like it automatically gives you the games.